# $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots\}$ where $A_n$ are sets $\forall n \in \omega$. We say $A$ is increasing if for all $n \in \omega$ $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ and $A$ is decreasing if for all $n \in \omega$ $A_{n+1} \subset A_n$. Prove if $A$ is increasing or decreasing then $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$$

**Attempt** Suppose $A$ is decreasing then $A_n \supset A_{n+1} \supset A_{n+1} \supset \cdots \supset \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k$ for all $n \in \omega$ then let $B=\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k$. So,

$A_n- B \supset A_{n+1}-B \supset A_{n+2}-B \supset \cdots$ then

\begin{align}
A_1 & = (A_1 - A_2) \cup (A_2-A_3 \cup (A_3-A_4) \cup \cdots \\
A_2 & = (A_2 - A_3) \cup (A_3-A_4 \cup (A_4-A_5) \cup \cdots \\
& \,\,\,\vdots \\
A_n & = (A_n - A_{n+1}) \cup (A_{n+2}-A_{n+3}) \cup (A_{n+3}-A_{n+4}) \cup\cdots
\end{align}

but what is the union, i don't understand how i can proceed, could you give me please?

Answer (score 1):

The two sets in the question are often named as $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k \equiv A_n\ \text{ev}$ for "$A_n$ eventually" and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k\equiv A_n\ \text{i.o.}$ for "$A_n$ infinitely often." Note that we always have $A_n\ \text{ev}\subset A_n\ \text{i.o.}$, so you have to show that if the $A_n$ are increasing or decreasing, then $A_n\ \text{i.o.}\subset A_n\ \text{ev}$.

If the $A_n$ are increasing, and $x\in A_n\ \text{i.o.}$, then in particular, $x$ is in some $A_k$, and hence $x\in A_n$ for all $k\ge n$. Thus $A_n\ \text{i.o}\subset A_n\ \text{ev}$ when the $A_n$ are increasing.

If the $A_n$ are decreasing, then the complements $A_n^c$ are increasing, so by the reasoning we just used, $A_n^c\ \text{i.o.} \subset A_n^c\ \text{ev}$. Use De Morgan's laws to show $(A_n\ \text{ev})^c = A_n^c\ \text{i.o.}$ and $(A_n\ \text{i.o.})^c = A_n^c\ \text{ev}$ to conclude that $A_n\ \text{ev}\subset A_n\ \text{i.o.}$

Comment: I must have misunderstood since I found this suspiciously obvious. Consider the decreasing case. For any $k$ we have: $\cap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k=A_n$ and thus, the LHS union term is $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=A_1$. Again because for all $n$, we can see that $\cup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k=A_n$, so the RHS is $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=A_1$ also. Similarly for the increasing case we try to show that both sides equal the quantity $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$. My guess is somewhere I'm making a blatant assumption about infinite sets? Please let me know.

Comment: @highgardener: If they’re decreasing, $\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_k=\bigcap_{k\ge 1}A_k$ for all $n$, so the LHS is $\bigcap_{k\ge 1}A_k$. And $\bigcup_{k\ge n}A_k=A_n$, so the RHS is also $\bigcap_{k\ge 1}A_k$. You are right about the increasing case.

Comment: @highgardener: Your first equality is correct if the $A_n$ are increasing, but not when they are decreasing, in general. I am not sure if you simply had a reversal where you were imagining increasing sets, but for a concrete example, you can take $A_n$ to be the closed interval $[0,1/n]$ in $\mathbb R$. I rewrote my answer—hopefully this time the answer is clear, but not suspiciously so.

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott. Yes I made a mistake. In the decreasing case,$\cap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$=$\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$. So in a way yeah trying to show that in the decreasing case they are both equal to the global intersection and in the increasing case the global union.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz yes it was. Thanks for the example and the rewrite. Very clear now.